# Autoreleased variable crashes in iOS 7.1 update, but working fine in OS versions prior to iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7.1

I face a strange issue. I had a piece of code as follows:

```
UIView *myView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 380)] autorelease];
// then I add some view componetns to this view...
[self.view addSubView:myView];
[myView release];
```

According to my understanding this piece of code will crash once the release message is called on myView variable, or once the autorelease pool drain happens on the thread.

However, this piece of code works fine in iOS versions prior to iOS 7.1 (I tested in iOS 6.0, 7.0, 7.0.4). But it crashes in iOS 7.1 and 7.1.1 updates.

Can someone give me the exact reason for the memory release crash happening. Any why does it not crash in the earlier versions.

Comment: you better use ARC in your project

Comment: @robmayoff Are you sure? He autoreleases and then manually releases.

Comment: I failed to scroll to the right.  ;^). That's why I deleted my comment.

Comment: It doesn't crash in earlier versions because an over-release is undefined behavior, and undefined behavior is not required to be predictable.  However, if you run with zombies enabled, you'll probably detect the error on earlier iOS versions too.

Comment: @robmayoff Not necessarily. If the system over-retained an object for any reason, it may not be immediately detectable.

Answer (score 1):

You are releasing `myView` incorrectly. Either let the autorelease pool release `myView` when it is drained, or release it manually by calling `release`. Right now, you release it once at the end of the method, then it is released incorrectly again by the autorelease drain, causing the object to be deallocated. The system then tries to access the view and crashes.

`addSubviews:` increases the retain count, and you release it right away. Then the autorelease releases the init retain by the allocation/init.

As to why it does not crash, it is not really important. Could be the system is over-retaining the view and thus the object remaining live while it no longer does in 7.1. But that is of no importance, the problem is in your code.

Comment: wait, `addSubview:` doesn't increment retain counter?

Comment: There's no retain counter without ARC, is there?

Comment: @gaussblurinc yes it does, but that's irrelevant to the answer.

Comment: @jrturton, can't understand why OP code is incorrect. two retains, two releases. Only because somewhere in view life `myView` is deallocated and iOS 7.1 try to access it?

Comment: @gaussblurinc `addSubviews:` increases the retain count, and you release it right away. Then the `autorelease` releases the init retain by the allocation/init.

Comment: There is only one retain that the OPs code should be releasing, and that is the original one where the view is created. The retain where the view is added to the subview is not up to him to balance, so he is prematurely releasing it. We don't know what happens inside a UIView when the subview is added.

Answer (score 0):

You already use autorelease while allocating memory for object and again you are releasing that after adding in view. You either remove autorelease or remove [myView release].